# Stored Function Error: No converter found capable of converting from type

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, stored-functions

I created stored function in PostgreSQL. I am getting proper result in PostgreSQL. But when I am trying to call stored function in spring data jpa using native query.  I am getting following error.

```
No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [com.spacestudy.model.ClientRT]"
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface ClientRoomTypeRepository extends JpaRepository<ClientRoomType, Integer> {


    @Query(nativeQuery = true,value = "select * from roomtype(:int_inst_id)")
    List<ClientRT> roomtype(@Param("int_inst_id")Integer int_inst_id);    
}
```

**Result class ClientRT**

```
public class ClientRT {

    public Integer res_nclient_room_type_id;    
    public String res_sclient_rt_desc;
    public String  res_sclient_rt_name;
    public String res_sclient_rt_code;
      //getter and setter
      ...
}
```

**PostgrSQL Result**

[image]

Comment: is ClientRT is an entity.?

Comment: no that is not an entity. That I created only for return

Comment: Then how can jpa map the result to that POJO.?

Comment: means return class need to make as an entity. but I don't have that table in db then is there any another way to return it

Comment: then you have to implement your own logic to get the data from object adn set it into POJO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a logic like this that I have used in my project that might be worked for you or may not. I have not used it with JPA object mapping.

```
public class ObjectSerializer {

private static ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@Autowired
public ObjectSerializer(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    ObjectSerializer.objectMapper = objectMapper;
}

public static <T> T getObject(Object obj, Class<T> class1) {
    String jsonObj = "";
    T userDto = null;
    try {
        jsonObj = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
        userDto = (T) objectMapper.readValue(jsonObj, class1);
        System.out.println(jsonObj);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException jpe) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return userDto;
}
```

}

Hope this will help.

Comment: I changed return type of repository method as `List<object>`. I got result but that is not in json format  [
 `[
    1,
    "TEMPORARILY NOT ASSIGNED",
    "TEMPORARILY NOT ASSIGNED",
    "000"
  ],`

Comment: Use this method and pass the object to it along with pojo that you want to convert in. Hope this helps.

Comment: this crt  is result of sp : `List<Object> crt=crtRepo.roomtype(60);`  should i pass crt at place of obj

Comment: yes, you should pass object at the place of object and any class to set the data into that, at the place of class.

Comment: like this`public static <T> T getObject(Object crt, ClientRT class1) {`

Comment: You just need to call the method with arguments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191211/discussion-between-pawan-tiwari-and-springuser).

Comment: Error: 
`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.spacestudy.model.ClientRT out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (String)"[1,"TEMPORARILY NOT ASSIGNED","TEMPORARILY NOT ASSIGNED","000"]"; line: 1, column: 1]  `